# link_to and :hover not working on my rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my button

```
<%= link_to "Contact Me", contact_path, class: "btn btn-flat" %>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.btn-flat {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #1EDD88;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

.btn-flat:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

that exact path works in my navbar so not sure why it isn't working here. effects like :after weren't working either. I have used other classes besides 'btn' as well so it is not related to bootstrap overriding anything.

Comment: Try changing `background` to `background-color` - both properties and within `transition`? I am not sure if `background` is transistable. Also, do check in the developers tools that `.btn-flat` and `.btn-flat:hover` has no `!Important` properties from bootstrap

Comment: that didn't work either. I'm concerned it's something more than just a simple css problem considering the link_to isn't working either. I just have no idea what could be causing both to not function properly.

Comment: okay actually the button works once my page has been collapsed to a certain size. once my navbar disappears the button works.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are using is bootstrap class that's why it's not working.
use your own class like

```
<%= link_to "Contact Me", contact_path, class: "btncontact btn btn-flat" %>
```

Comment: I tried deleting the bootstrap class but it still isn't functioning. I've tried adding other link_to's on the page but they aren't working either.

Comment: in which file you put your css

Comment: okay actually the button works once my page has been collapsed to a certain size. once my navbar disappears the button works.

Comment: let's connect to any platform so that i can look what exactly happening with the code.

Comment: It was related to bootstrap. The navbar-collapse class was messing with other things. thank you for the offer though!